# Mongoose/Node If document exists, edit data, resubmit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a Mongo Document using Mongoose and Node. However, I want to know that it is unique and if it isn't then add a count.

A simple example would be, create a user with a username.  If username John is taken, iterate through and create one with John1.  However, if John1 is taken, keep going through until JohnX is free and then save the document.

```
    var record = new Record();
    record.name = 'John';
    record.username = 'John';

    var keepGoing = true;
    var x=1;
    while(keepGoing){
        Record.findOne({username: record.username}, function(err, result){
            console.log('Check I get here');
            if(result!=null){
                // User Exists, try a new username;
                record.username = 'John' +  x;
                x++;
            }
            else{
               keepGoing= false;
               record.save .....
               ....
            }
         });
    }
```

This current code ends up going into an infinite loop.  If I remove the While loop my console.log executes, however, when I put it back into the while loop, it doesn't seem to hit my console.log.  Would really appreciate any insights.

Comment: Read about ["upserts"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) and the [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator in the documentation. It's going to save a lot on processing overhead and logic.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed my algorithm now to take a different approach based on this.

Comment: Good. Common sense would say to keep a "counters" collection keyed on the "root" of the name stripped of numbers. A `.findOneAndUpdate()` with an `$inc` would be a very fast way to get the next available number for assigning the next numeric value for each "root".

Answer (score 0):

Here could be one workaround, using [`distinct`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-distinct) to find all `username`, then sort it to get the max username, then save this new username record.

```
Record.distinct('username', function(err, usernames){
     if (err)
        console.log(err);
     else {
        // sort the username, then pop the last name
        var un = usernames.sort().pop();

        var reg = /\d+/g;
        // get the current max number in username,
        var num = parseInt(un.match(reg)[0]);
        var newusername = 'John' + (++num);

        // insert new username record
        var r = new Record({username: newusername});
        r.save(function(err) {});
     }
});
```

Comment: **Or** consider that `["John","John1","John2"]` is potentially going to eventually yield a **very large array** in any meaningful system. So probably not the best course of action for anything more than a "toy" application.